# Study the uniform convergence of the functional sequence $f_n(x)=\sqrt{n+1}\sin^nx\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Study the uniform convergence of the functional sequence $f_n(x)=\sqrt{n+1}\sin^nx\cos x$

I found the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=0$$

The solution in the book it says that since

$$d_n=\sup_{x \in \mathbb R}|\sqrt{n+1}\sin^nx\cos x|=\left(\sqrt{ \frac{n}{n+1}}\right)^n \to \frac 1{\sqrt e}$$

when $n \to \infty$ then the convergence cannot be uniform in $\mathbb R$. But I don't understand how did they get that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact since the limit function $f(x)$ is equal to zero every where we have$$d_n=\sup_{\Bbb R} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$$The uniform convergence states that $$\forall \epsilon >0\quad,\quad\exists N\quad,\quad n>N\implies d_n<\epsilon$$which is impossible since $d_n\to {1\over \sqrt e}$ as is proved.

**P.S.**

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{ \frac{n}{n+1}}\right)^n{=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}{n\over 2}\ln{n\over n+1}\right)\\=\exp\left(\lim_{u\to 0}{1\over 2u}\ln{1\over u+1}\right)\\=\exp\left(\lim_{u\to 0}-{1\over 2}{1\over u+1}\right)\\={1\over \sqrt e}}$$where we have used the L^Hopital's rule.

Comment: I understood that, but I don't know how did they get $d_n \to \frac1{\sqrt e} $

Comment: I added some details. Hope it help!

Comment: I think I'm not making myself clear. I don't know why $\sup_{x \in \mathbb R}|\sqrt{n+1}\sin^nx\cos x|=\left(\sqrt{ \frac{n}{n+1}}\right)^n$

Comment: This is obtained from 1st order differentiation. Note that$$f'_n(x)=\sqrt{n+1}\{n\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos^2x-\sin^n(x)\}=0$$then either $$\sin x=0$$or$$n\sin^2x+\sin x-n=0 \implies \sin(x)={-1+\sqrt{4n^2+1}\over 2n}$$Now what happens when you